# From C# to F#: Pinned Array and Stringbuilder in external function called from F#

Tags: arrays, f#, pinvoke, external, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to access an external DLL function from F#.
This one has me really sweating.

The C header is:

```
ext_def(int32) swe_calc_ut(double tjd_ut, int32 ipl, int32 iflag, 
double *xx, char *serr);
```

I imported that in F# accordingly:

```
extern int32 ext_swe_calc_ut(double tjd_ut, int32 ipl, int32 iflag, double *xx, StringBuilder serr);
```

The problem is the array part. I tried PinnedArray from F# Powerpack, but the call still fails. The char array is probably ok, even though I can't check since the call fails.

So far it is:

```
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open System.Text
open Microsoft.FSharp.NativeInterop

#r "FSharp.PowerPack.dll" 
#nowarn "51"

module Sweph =

    [<DllImport(@"swedll32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "swe_calc_ut")>]
    extern int32 ext_swe_calc_ut(double tjd_ut, int32 ipl, int32 iflag, double *xx, StringBuilder serr);
    /// <param name="jdnr">Julian day</param>
    /// <returns>Array with 6 doubles: 0:longitude, 1:latitude, 2:distance,3:speel in longitude, 
    ///          4: speed in latitude, 5: speed in distance </returns>


let ar: double array = Array.zeroCreate 6
let argx = PinnedArray.of_array ar

printfn "  ar: %A" ar

// This fails with a "FileLoadException"
printfn "ar: %A" argx

// Details of FileLoadException:
(*
```

"FSharp.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" not matching assembly (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131040)
    *)

```
// However, if I leave the printfn for argx out, code continues and does not display this error again.

let sb = new StringBuilder(50)          // Vgl. Expert F#, S. 515

Console.ReadKey(true)


// Application crashes here:
let ret_calc = Sweph.ext_swe_calc_ut(4700.0,1,1,argx.Ptr,sb)
```

The program crashes at this point (the console window disappears and in debugging, it just jumps back to the first line.

I'm aware that I could use "use" instead of "let" with "let argx = PinnedArray.of_array ar", but the compiler won't let me have it because of a module declaration at the top.

There is an implementation in C# like this:

```
    public static double[] getPlanet(int ipl, double jdnr) {
        //   String ephePath = "Q:\\sweph\\";
        //   Sweph.setEphePath(ephePath);
        double[] xx2 = new double[8];
        double[] xx = new double[6];
        String serr = "";
        int iflag = Constants.SEFLG_SPEED;
        long iflgret = ext_swe_calc_ut(jdnr, ipl, iflag, xx, serr);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
            xx2[i] = xx[i]; 
        }
        iflag = Constants.SEFLG_SWIEPH | Constants.SEFLG_SPEED | Constants.SEFLG_EQUATORIAL;
        iflgret = ext_swe_calc_ut(jdnr, ipl, iflag, xx, serr);
        xx2[6] = xx[0];
        xx2[7] = xx[1];

        return xx2;
    }
```

Maybe the whole problem goes back to the FileLoad exception (even though that is not displayed in the dll call) - possibly because of the FSharp Powerpack?

Thank you very much for your help indeed.

Comment: Maybe it could be done without the PinnedArray? That might avoid the problem altogether - but would memory allocation still work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my guess, based on the C type signature and the [function documentation](http://www.astro.com/swisseph/swephprg.htm#_Toc335137304) I found. It compiles, but you'll have to tell me if it actually works since I don't have the `swedll32.dll` assembly. Also, my code doesn't require the F# Powerpack assembly.

EDIT: Just read the comments under @kvb's answer -- he suggested the same thing I included in my code, which is the `[<MarshalAs(...)>]` attribute with the `SizeConst` property set. I also added `[<Out>]`, because the last two parameters are used as return values; IIRC, it also affects marshalling behavior.

EDIT 2: Removed the `ExactSpelling = true` from the `MarshalAs` attribute, as per @wolfgang's report.

```
[<DllImport(@"swedll32.dll",
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
    EntryPoint = "swe_calc_ut")>]
extern int32 swe_calc_ut (
    float tjd_ut,
    int32 ipl,
    int32 flag,
    [<Out; MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 6)>]
    float[] xx,
    [<Out; MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 256)>]
    System.Text.StringBuilder serr)

// Wrapper function for swe_calc_ut
let swe_calc_ut_wrapper (tjd_ut, ipl, flag) =
    let positions = Array.zeroCreate 6
    let errorSB = System.Text.StringBuilder (256)
    let result = swe_calc_ut (tjd_ut, ipl, flag, positions, errorSB)
    if result < 0 then
        // Error
        Choice2Of2 (result, errorSB.ToString ())
    else
        Choice1Of2 positions
```

Comment: Seems like sorcery. 4 am. Will try.

Comment: Wohoo! Yahoo! It compiles! You guys are awesome! Is there a "buy you a beer" button? :-)  (Just had to remove the "Exact spelling" option.) Will send this to the makers of Swiss ephemeris to spare coming generations troubles and woes ;-)
Happy theologian from Switzerland hunting for "Star of Bethlehem" combinations for his habilitation thesis

Answer (score 1):

You might try to use functionality from the `System.Runtime.Interop` namespace rather than relying on the F# PowerPack.  I think you'd want to try something like:

```
let hndl = GCHandle.Alloc(ar, GCHandleType.Pinned)
let ptr : double nativeptr = 
    hndl.AddrOfPinnedObject() 
    |> NativePtr.ofNativeInt

let ret_calc = Sweph.ext_swe_calc_ut(4700.0,1,1,ptr,sb)

hndl.Free()
```

However, it looks like the C# code is using a different interop signature - it's marshaling `xx` as a `double[]` and `serr` as a `string` (and looks like it's probably returning an `int64`).  If that code works, you might want to just do the same thing in F#...

Comment: Thank you very much, will try that. 
Concerning the int64: I thought that, too, but it says "ext_def(int32) " in the C header.

Comment: The FileLoadException went away after I realized that FSharpPowerpack offers two download: the older one with direct link and the newer one (for FS 3.0) via NuGet.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new to this - how would your solution for the marshaling look like? Didn't get anywhere trying it. Not familiar with F#.

Comment: @Wolfgang - What do you mean by "the handle construct doesn't work"?  Same error as before?  Compile time error?  Different runtime error?

Comment: @Wolfgang - As to the signature, my suggestion was to change `double* xx` to `double[] xx` and `StringBuilder serr` to `string serr`, and then just pass the array directly rather than dealing with pointers.

Comment: @Wolfgang - But you may need some extra attibutes (e.g. to specify the array size during marshaling).  What does the C# PInvoke signature look like?

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions - it is evening now here, getting back it it tomorrow. Failure with the handle construct was same as before - the program just quits, no error message or anything, Console window disappers.

Comment: C# PInvoke Header:

        [DllImport("swedll32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "swe_calc_ut")]
        private extern static long ext_swe_calc_ut(double jdnr, int ipl, int iflag, double[] xx, String serr);